# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, cookie, php-faq

Не сохраняются куки. Что не так.

Ошибка

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at blocksSite/main_noauth.php:4) in blocksSite/main_noauth.php on line 58

Comment: значит перед этим было что то выведено. Проверьте классические проблемы

 - перед первым `<?php` нет пробелов или пустых строк.
 - после последнего `?>` нет пробелов или пустых строк.
 - Ваш код не выводит с помощью echo/pring что то до установки кук
 - что текст сохранен без BOM. Если Вы пользуетесь блокнотом или подобным, то они могут добавлять в начало, если сохраняете в UTF-8.

Comment: _Классические проблемы - перед первым `<?php` нет пробелов или пустых строк. После последнего `?>` нет пробелов или пустых строк._ – Решил проблему, были пустые строки после `?>`.

Answer (score 50):

Общение WEB-сервера с клиентом в данном случае происходит по [протоколу HTTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP). HTTP включает в себя [HTTP заголовки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_HTTP) и тело ответа. При этом заголовки обязательно следуют перед телом ответа  – того требует стандарт.

PHP же в свою очередь в процессе работы должен сформировать и заголовки и тело ответа. Даже если Вы не задаете ни одного заголовка, то PHP сам устанавливает все необходимые заголовки для ответа клиенту. При этом данные, которые необходимо отдать клиенту он записывает сначала в [буфер](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.outcontrol.php), но если он начал писать в буфер тело ответа, то заголовки он уже никак не может туда записать и встретив попытку записи заголовков ответа уже после того, как начало формироваться тело ответа PHP выдает ошибку:

```
  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...
```

Это может быть следствием следующих причин:

1. Перед установкой заголовков был вывод тела ответа. При этом вывод может быть осуществлен как средствами шаблонизатора, так и через функции [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php) или [print](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php)

   ```
   <html> // вывод средствами шаблонизатора
   <?php
       echo "<body>"; // вывод средствами оператора
       header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
   ```
2. Вы можете банально ошибиться и поставить перед `<?` пробелы или переносы строк, которые тоже будут восприняты как тело ответа.
3. Ровно так же как и в пункте 2, но в конце php-файла:
   Файл **incrementX.php**

   ```
   <?php
   $x++;
   ?>[пробел][перенос строки]
   ```

   Файл **index.php**

   ```
   <?php
   include( "incrementX.php" );
   header( ... );
   ```
4. Файлы, которые содержат PHP-код должны быть сохранены без [BOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). [Как сохранить файл без BOM](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+bom&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+bom).
5. Не забывайте, что если Вы подключаете файлы через [include или require](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), то файлы к которым обращаются эти функции также могут содержать одну из трех вышеперечисленных проблем.

   ```
    include( "include.inc" ); // include.inc может формировать тело ответа  
    header( ... );
   ```
6. Если настроен вывод ошибок в браузер, то **warning** тоже будет телом ответа:

   ```
    $filename= "";
    $text= file_get_contents( $filename ); // Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
    header( ... );
   ```

Самым правильным решением большинства проблем с выводом заголовков является изменение структуры РНР файла таким образом, чтобы весь вывод начинался только после того, как отработала основная логика скрипта.

Если же приходится работать с устаревшим кодом где всё вперемешку, можно воспользоваться буферизацией вывода явным образом:

```
    <? ob_start();?>
    <html>
    <?php
        echo "<body>";
        header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
        ob_end_flush();
```

либо настройками php.ini принудить PHP сперва наполнять буфер данными до определенного размера, и лишь потом отдавать содержимое буфера клиенту, но в этом случае превысив размер буфера Вы увидите Выше описываемую ошибку.

```
    output_buffering = 14096
```

Comment: а можно, дабавить в php.ini output_buffering = 14096

и ничего не делать :)

но вообще да, таких ситуаций быть не должно

Comment: а в один день запишете 14097 байт и будете долго ломать голову.

> но вообще да, таких ситуаций быть не должно

вообще то это родовая травма php...

Comment: >> а в один день запишете 14097 байт и будете долго ломать голову.

в последних версиях пхп - оно по умолчанию установлено

Comment: Обсуждали в чате ([раз](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34891417#34891417) и [два](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34898831#34898831)), не стоит ли навесить на этот вопрос метку php-faq и использовать ваш ответ как эталонную закрывашку для подобных вопросов по ошибке cannot modify header info. Не возьмётесь ли дополнить свой ответ ссылкой на http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/ и дописать (с него или другого сайта) недостающую информацию?

Comment: Добавляйте, если считаете нужным... Я просто не оттуда брал информацию, а из головы, ну и мой ответ рассматривает больше типичных ошибок, чем обозначенный сайт.

Answer (score 6):

у вас что-то эхнуто перед отправкой хедера `...main_noauth.php on line 58...`. Посмотрите в строчке 58

Comment: Развернутый ответ...

Comment: минусните меня если я не прав)

Comment: Технически Вы несомненно правы ))))

Comment: Я тут новенький, я научусь

Comment: Холмс:
- Это программист.
- Черт возьми Холмс, как вы догадались?
- Элементарно, Ватсон. Он дал абсолютно точный, но совершенно бесполезный ответ.

Comment: За прогера - от души))

Comment: На самом деле проблема на четвёртой строчке.

Answer (score 0):

В php.ini

```
output_buffering = On
```

И всё работает

Comment: Присоединяюсь к Олегу.
Была такая же проблема с запуском приложения на yii(advanced)
После включения буферизации в настройках php проблема исчезла