# Не могу записать значение переменной в cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Строчка `setcookie('name', $name);`
Вызывает ошибку `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\urok5.com\index.php:1)`
Почему так происходит? Не могу записать данные из переменной в cookie.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by А вообще, это гуглится за три секунды, сначала отсылаются заголовки http-ответа, потом - тело ответа, и, видимо, тело вы уже отправили, а потом хотите отправить заголовок, так не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто cookie передаются в http заголовке, до тела с ответом ( контентом) ты пытаешься передать cookie уже после того как что то отдал браузеру... вот он и ругается, у тебя наверное где то Warningги или другие ошибки выскакивают, посмотри что в самом начале страницы?

во общем запомни:

1) ставишь cookie

2) потом все остальное