# Почему при utf-8 не работает session_start();

Tags: php

Перевел скрипт в utf-8 и перестали работать сесии и стили .. как справиться с этим?

Comment: Во-первых показать весь код, в том числе и стили, и активацию сессии.

Comment: попробуй сохранить utf-8 bom

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сохранить документ в формате UTF-8 без BOM. Справится с этим может тот же самый Notepad++ и убедитесь что `session_start();` поставлена самой первой строчкой. А суть ошибки заключается в том, что при обычном сохранении UTF-8, есть такая штука как Byte Order Mask, которая добавляет тот самый несчастный символ в начало файла.

Comment: спасибо помогло