# При нажатии на кнопку перекидывает на указанную страницу

Tags: php, html

Есть кнопка удаление товара:

```
<a href="cart.php?id='.$row["cart_id"].'&action=delete" class="btn btn--small btn--secondary cart__remove">Удалить2</a>
```

При нажатии перекидывает на страницу 123.ru/**cart.php?id=11&action=delete**

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии товар так же удалялся но перекидывало на страницу 123.ru

Comment: Нужно, так сделай.

Answer (score -1):

Значит в конце обработчика (в php файле) надо писать **[header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)**

Пример такого:

```
header('Location: http://123.ru/'); // header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
exit;
```

---

При этом может возникнуть ошибка

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

потому что надо помнить:

> Функцию **header()** можно вызывать только если клиенту еще не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.

Более подробнее о том как устранить данную ошибку, если она возникнет - можно почитать тут: **[Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/284578/191482)**

Comment: опять какие-то сумасшедшие ерундой страдают