# Почему не работает header()?

Tags: php

```
<?

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('blog');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
        $id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users`");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
        $user = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if(!empty($user))
        {
            session_start();


            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            echo('Вы успешно авторизовались ');
            echo($id);
            header('Location: http://blog.pro/profile');
        }
        else
        {
            echo('Имя пользователя или пароль указаны неправильно');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo('Заполните все поля');
    }
}

?>
```

Выдает ошибку

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at Z:\home\blog.pro\www\login.php:23) in
>   Z:\home\blog.pro\www\login.php on line 25

Comment: А что говорят логи?

Comment: @KostaB. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\blog.pro\www\login.php:23) in Z:\home\blog.pro\www\login.php on line 25

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед использованием функции [header()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) не должно быть вывода информации.

> Помните, что функцию **header()** можно вызывать только если клиенту еще
>   не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед
>   ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.
>   Довольно часто возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми
>   функциями, вроде include или require, в этом коде попадаются пробелы
>   или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова header(). Те же
>   проблемы могут возникать и при использовании PHP/HTML в одном файле.

Если будет вывод информации перед использованием функции **header()**, тогда будет выдана ошибка

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at ...) in ... on line ...

Вам нужно убрать вывод информации:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

//echo('Вы успешно авторизовались ');
//echo($id);
header('Location: http://blog.pro/profile');
```