# Выдает ошибку в header();

Tags: php

При правильном перенаправлении выдает такую ошибку:

> User Registered..
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\OpenServer\domains\websocket\index.php:13).

Хотя здесь условие выполняется.

```
if ($objUser->save()) {
  echo "User Registered..";
  header("Location: chatroom.php");
  exit;
} else{
  echo "Failed..";
}
```

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/284578/199253)  - каноничный ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, научитесь читать ошибки и пользоваться поиском, таких вопросов уже тьма.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `header()` должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.
Удалите `echo` перед ней