# ошибка cookie php

Tags: php

Сейчас учу php,дошел до изучения куки,но функция setcookie не работает ни в какую и вызывает ошибку.Вот собственно код(даже скопи-пастил код из офф.документации по php и все равно тщетно)

```php
<?php
    $text = 'textforcookie';
    setcookie('textcookie',$text);
    echo "{$_COOKIE['textcookie']}";
?>
```

Текст ошибки: **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\lesson\index.php:1) in C:\OSPanel\domains\lesson\index.php on line 13**

Есть подозрение на локальный сервер,использую OpenServer Ultimate

Comment: Есть подозрение что вы не умеете пользоваться поиском. Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Answer (score 3):

У вас до `<?php` идёт вывод информации на экран. Возможно просто пробел перед `<?php` или перенос строки или может до этого ещё какой-то код написан.
Помните, что передавать заголовки можно только если клиенту еще не передавались данные.

Comment: удалил весь код кроме этого,убрал все отступы,тщетно

Comment: @daladn0 дело в `echo`. Его надо удалить

Comment: @СергейМишин вроде нет, он идёт после отправки заголовка

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в небольшом куске `html` кода который шел до него. Пока не понимаю как это связано:) По отдельности `html` код выводился корректно и ошибок в нем не было, `php` код тоже сам по себе нормально работает. Но вместе почему-то не вяжутся, не судьба видимо ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Уважаемый, ответ выше повествует вам об этом? Вы ответ читали?