# Простая перезагрузка страницы. PHP

Tags: php

Есть код наподобие этого.

```
$condition = ...
    if($condition) {
      Перезагрузка страницы.
}
```

Но что-бы я не пробовал,никак не могу перезагрузить страницу , header не работает, если использую script страница перезагружается вечно, ajax к сожелению не знаю. 
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: и что вы имеете в виду под перезагрузкой страницы? особенно если учесть, что во время обработки этого условия страница еще не отправлена пользователю, а сервер только формирует ответ.

Comment: Чтобы `header();` работал, вам необходимо структурировать код таким образом, чтобы все echo/print/var_dump'ы и прочий вывод или html разметка шли строго после `header()` .

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы дать указание браузеру запросить ту или иную страницу, необходимо отправить ему НТТР заголовок `Location:` с помощью функции `header()`:

```
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
exit;
```

Данный код выполнит перенаправление ровно на ту же самую страницу, на которой был вызван, поскольку в переменной `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` содержится полный адрес, который запрашивал браузер, обращаясь к этому скрипту. Если нужен адрес без строки запроса ("GET параметров"), то его можно получить так: `strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');`

Кроме того, надо не забывать завершать работу скрипта принудительно с помощью `exit`, поскольку сама по себе отправка заголовка не завершает работу кода, и он продолжает выполняться дальше.

Если "header не работает", то скорее всего либо просто ошибка в коде, либо это печально известная ошибка [Headers already sent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/284587/179379), которая объясняется тем, что что `Location:` - это НТТР заголовок, то есть **перед ним не должно быть** любого вывода, включая, разумеется, html теги.

Чтобы не было циклического перенаправления, надо заключать код в условие.
Например, самый распространенный вариант проверить отправку формы, это

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Обработка формы
    header("Location:" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
    exit;
}
```

И в этом случае циклического перенаправления никогда не будет, поскольку перенаправление делается методом GET

Comment: А инного способа не существует , ибо у меня дело такое. 
Есть таблица, там кнопка удалить, как пользователь нажимает кнопку удалить запись удаляется из бд, но в таблице остается, поэтому хочу сделать рестарт страницы чтобы она исчезла.

Comment: Вот поэтому в вопросе надо описывать __реальную проблему__ а не свое гипотетическое решение. И да - Ajax и редиректы в таком виде как у вас - несовместимы.

Comment: А зачем ты хочешь что бы пропала запись перезагружать страницу, ты и сервер и пользователя грузишь, просто поставь display: none у того элемента, на который нажали, он скроется, а при следующей перезагрузке его уже не будет

Comment: Ой, как я мог не додуматься . Спасибо <3