# Ошибка при авторизации на PHP

Tags: php

помогите решить проблему.
Делаю авторизацию на сайте, и при нажатии на кнопку проверяю все ли данные введены правильно, суть в том что если данные правильно то я перевожу на другую страницу и устанавливаю куки. Но когда я их устанавливаю у меня выводит ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка которую выводит при нажатии на кнопку. Не важно даже что туда вводить, он всё ровно выводит ошибку и через 3 секунды переводит на страницу panel.php но куки не ставятся.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код — текстом..

Comment: До того как сразу задавать вопрос, можно было бы поискать информацию по данной ошибке, а? эта ошибка(данная тема) старше Ситхов и всей галактики :) Вы пробуете работать с куки после того, как заголовки уже отправлены.... Очень внимательно читаем - http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers

Comment: Не сдержался, должен задать один вопрос :) :) . В скрине увидел сообщение,  если нет результатов из базы показывать текст :) такие сообщения стимулируют вас писать работающий код??  :)

Comment: Arsen, если это вас так интересует, то да.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie` работает с заголовками.
Вы пытаетесь задать заголовки когда уже вывели какое-то содержимое, в данном случае редирект на js.
Поменяйте местами строчки кода (сначала ставим куки, потом делаем редирект).

Comment: Менял миллион раз, проблема не уходит