# Не работает переход на другую страницу PHP

Tags: php, mysql, header

```
<?php 
    header('Location: B:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\index.php'); 
?>
```

Выдает ошибку:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at B:\OpenServer\domains\registr\reg.php:1)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    header('Location: www.site.ru'); 
?>
```

Путь локальный работать не будет, только url можно указать, или путь к файлу от корня папки сайта /localhost/

```
<?php 
        header('Location: index.php'); 
?>
```