# Ошибка в php sqli

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Ошибка #1:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ### on line 16

Ошибка #2:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ###) in ### on line 24

Код:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1" , "root" , "Пароль");

mysqli_select_db($con, 'users');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = " select * from usertable2 where name = '$name' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
    header('location:errors/already-named.php');
}else{
    $reg = " insert into usertable2(name, password) values ('$name' , '$pass') ";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);

    header('location:login.php');
} ?>
```

Не знаю в чём проблема, всё с названиями если что правильно - [image: Логин и пароль] [image: БД Список]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole)

Comment: ну и второй дубликат: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/284578/191482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лол спустя 10 минут просмотра кода и проверки названий понял что вместо name в $s и $reg нужно поставить user, вот новый рабочий код:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1" , "root" , "Пароль");

mysqli_select_db($con, 'users');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = " select * from usertable2 where user = '$name' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
    header('location:errors/already-named.php');
}else{
    $reg = " insert into usertable2(user, password) values ('$name' , '$pass') ";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);

    header('location:login.php');
} ?>
```