# WP. Ошибка Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: wordpress

Конечно же я изучил вопрос прежде чем задавать его тут, перекапал множество ссылок.

Сайт на хостинге timeweb. Ошибку Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...  вызвала попытка установить плагин, всего то, из консоли, совместимый с версией WP, сам плагин проверенный многократно, конфликтов не вызывал никогда.

В чем вопрос. Я не силен относительно всего что связано с серваками, но, заметил что и ошибка склоняется к тому что один из вариантов - сервер и опыт. Это второй сайт на WP за неделю, на этом хостинге, где обычные действией, первое какое либо изменение, вызывает эту ошибку.

Для решения проблемы мониторил все файлы которые выкидываю исключение, на разных стр они разные. Каких то пробелов нет, ошибок тоже, да и файлы то, корневые самого движка, в них точно ничего не делалось

Возможно ли такое что все таки, проблема в timeweb или есть варианты исправить ситуацию еще как то

Comment: [Возможный дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284578/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/Cannot_modify_header_information

Comment: Благодарю за ответы. Пока что ничего не подходит.
Файлы точно не правились, вот точно, а даже если бы, я проверял те файлы на которые мне WP указывает. Там ничего нет, пробелов и тд. На разных страницах указывает разные файлы в которых есть якобы проблема

Comment: файлы темы, плагинов..  могли правиться не тобой. Ошибка говорит, что однозначно перед правильным заголовком запроса уже что-то вылетело.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Тем не менее. Все файлы на которые он мне указывал я прорыскивал, там вообще ничего нет )) Даже пробелов перед или после открывающих/закрывающих. 

Сложная ситуация в целом. 
Если что то иное провоцирует выдавать ошибку, что то, на что он никак сам не укажет

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее вероятная причина - плагин выдает ошибку или предупреждение при установке. Если `wp-config.php` содержит `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );`, то сообщение об ошибке выводится на экран раньше заголовков, что и вызывает описанную проблему.